# Server Transfer Not working

Tags: css, text, ftp

Ok so I transferred my website so far to a free domain through ftp. Some things aren't the right way though.

- The logo in the top right corner is not showing when clearly it's in the proper folder
- The text is not the same. I'm not sure how to transfer the text so it can be seen on any computer.
- The twitter, Facebook, and YouTube buttons and the gallery images all have either a white or blue box border over them which shouldn't be
- The slider on the first screen has 4 circles which are showing up as squares on some browsers

One other problem is that I can't get the links in the left box to stay that green color when active. My code has a:active though. If anyone can help with ANY of these problems I would be SO GREATLY APPRECIATED.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(about the text issue, I assumed you meant font)
I believe you are talking about using a font-face in css,

this works by upload the .ttf font file and referencing it as a custom font in your css like this:

In your css:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: my_font;
    src: url('/my_font.ttf');
}
```

and then you can reference it in css as usual

i.e

```
#text { 
    font-family: my_font;
}
```

Comment: o shoot SORRY i did mean font*. But ok thanks a lot!. If i just drag/put the .ttf files with the rest of the folders using ftp would that work too?

Comment: yes, but make sure you source the url of the font correctly in the src: part ;)

Answer (score 1):

> The logo in the top right corner is not showing when clearly it's in the proper folder

Systems are case sensitive. Make sure you match the case of the file name (hint, `e`).

> The text is not the same. I'm not sure how to transfer the text so it can be seen on any computer.

I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: for the text part I mean what you're seeing is not the text I set it too. How do I fix it so that you can see what text I ACTUALLY used

Answer (score 0):

(About keeping an active link lit up on the page)

You have three options to do this,

A. Completely with CSS :

say you have a menu that looks like this:

```
<ul>

<li><a href=”home.html”>Home</a>

<li><a href=”about.html”>Articles</a>

</ul>
```

all you need to do for starters is add unique id's to each item

like so:

```
<ul>

<li><a href=”home.html” id=”homenav”>Home</a>

<li><a href=”about.html” id=”aboutnav”>Articles</a>

</ul>
```

and add a body id for each page with a respective id

i.e

```
<body id="home">
```

at which point you can then make an easy css reference

that will work on every page as long as you change the body id on each like so:

```
body#home a#homenav, body#about a#aboutnav {
  color: #64f2f1;

}
```